# how to pagging with first,previous,next,last with mvc core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core

i have created one department table and i just want to apply first,previous,next,last hyper link with pagination to table here is my paging and view hyper text element code :

```
public class PagingList<T> : List<T>
    {
        public int PageIndex { get; private set; }
        public int TotalPages { get; private set; }

        public PagingList(List<T> items, int count, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
        {
            PageIndex = pageIndex;
            TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(count / (double)pageSize);

            this.AddRange(items);
        }

        public bool HasFirstPage
        {
            get
            {
                return (PageIndex == TotalPages);
            }
        }
        public bool HasPreviousPage
        {
            get
            {
                return (PageIndex > 1);
            }
        }

        public bool HasNextPage
        {
            get
            {
                return (PageIndex < TotalPages);
            }
        }


        public bool HasLastPage
        {
            get
            {
                return (PageIndex == 0);
            }
        }

        public int TotalPageNo
        {
            get
            {
                return TotalPages;
            }
        }

        public static PagingList<T> CreateAsync(IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
        {
            var count = source.Count();
            var items = source.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
            return new PagingList<T>(items, count, pageIndex, pageSize);
        }
    }
```

view code :

```
 @{
        var firstDisabled = !Model.HasFirstPage ? "disabled" : "";
        var prevDisabled = !Model.HasPreviousPage ? "disabled" : "";
        var nextDisabled = !Model.HasNextPage ? "disabled" : "";
        var totalPageNo = Model.TotalPageNo;
        var currentPageNo = Model.PageIndex;
        var lastDisabled = !Model.HasLastPage ? "disabled" : "";
    }
    
    <a asp-action="Index"
       asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["CurrentSort"]"
       asp-route-pageNo="@(Model.PageIndex == 1)"
       asp-route-currentFilter="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]"
       class="btn btn-default @firstDisabled">
        First
    </a>
    
    <a asp-action="Index"
       asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["CurrentSort"]"
       asp-route-pageNo="@(Model.PageIndex - 1)"
       asp-route-currentFilter="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]"
       class="btn btn-default @prevDisabled">
        Previous
    </a>
    <a asp-action="Index"
       asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["CurrentSort"]"
       asp-route-pageNo="@(Model.PageIndex + 1)"
       asp-route-currentFilter="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]"
       class="btn btn-default @nextDisabled">
        Next
    </a>
    <a asp-action="Index"
       asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["CurrentSort"]"
       asp-route-pageNo="@(Model.PageIndex == totalPageNo)"
       asp-route-currentFilter="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]"
       class="btn btn-default @lastDisabled">
        Last
    </a>
    <span>
        Page No : @currentPageNo of @totalPageNo
    </span>
```

this two hyper text link First and Last not works perfectally.please help me to out of this stuck..................

Answer (score 0):

with this class:

```
    public class PaginatedList<T> : List<T>
    {
        public int PageIndex { get; private set; }
        public int TotalPages { get; private set; }

        public PaginatedList(List<T> items, int count, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
        {
            PageIndex = pageIndex;
            TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(count / (double)pageSize);

            this.AddRange(items);
        }

        public bool HasFirstPage => PageIndex != 1;

        public bool HasPreviousPage => PageIndex > 1;

        public bool HasNextPage => PageIndex < TotalPages;

        public bool HasLastPage => PageIndex != TotalPages;

        public int TotalPageNo
        {
            get
            {
                return TotalPages;
            }
        }


        public static async Task<PaginatedList<T>> CreateAsync(IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
        {
            var count = await source.CountAsync();
            var items = await source.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
            return new PaginatedList<T>(items, count, pageIndex, pageSize);
        }
    }
```

And this on view

```
@{
        var firstDisabled = !Model.HasFirstPage ? "disabled" : "";
        var prevDisabled = !Model.HasPreviousPage ? "disabled" : "";
        var nextDisabled = !Model.HasNextPage ? "disabled" : "";
        var totalPageNo = Model.TotalPageNo;
        var currentPageNo = Model.PageIndex;
        var lastDisabled = !Model.HasLastPage ? "disabled" : "";
    }
    <nav>
        <ul class="pagination">
            <li class="page-item @firstDisabled">
                <a asp-action="Index"
                   asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["CurrentSort"]"
                   asp-route-pageNumber="@(1)"
                   asp-route-currentFilter="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]"
                   class="page-link">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-backward-fast"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="page-item @prevDisabled">
                <a asp-action="Index"
                   asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["CurrentSort"]"
                   asp-route-pageNumber="@(Model.PageIndex - 1)"
                   asp-route-currentFilter="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]"
                   class="page-link">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-backward-step"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="page-item  @nextDisabled">
                <a asp-action="Index"
                   asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["CurrentSort"]"
                   asp-route-pageNumber="@(Model.PageIndex + 1)"
                   asp-route-currentFilter="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]"
                   class="page-link">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-forward-step"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="page-item  @lastDisabled">
                <a asp-action="Index"
                   asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["CurrentSort"]"
                   asp-route-pageNumber="@(totalPageNo)"
                   asp-route-currentFilter="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]"
                   class="page-link">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-forward-fast"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    

    
    
    <span>
        Page : @currentPageNo sur @totalPageNo
    </span>
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?